# exchangeable middle layer in docker

Tags: docker

Is it possible in Docker to do samething like this

```
Image1: Linux 
Image2A: Python2.7 (FROM Image1)
Image2B: Python3.6  (FROM Image1)
Image3: install application  (FROM Image2A or FROM Image2B)

Image4A: Linux>Python2.7>applciation (FROM Image3 with same parameters that depend python2.7)
Image4B: Linux>Python3.6>applciation (FROM Image3 with same parameters that depend python3.6)
```

If is not possibile, how do recommend to plan it. Key point for me is that I have 
exchangeable middle layers and want to have easy way to build last layer.